# How to reach and modify child class's variables from parent class when child class is one of many Tkinter frames made visible container and tkraise()

Tags: python, tkinter, inheritance, initialization

I am writing a Python GUI application with `Tkinter` where I have several frames that I want to manage separately. I want to put these "child" frames in separate classes (and ultimately in different files) to make the overall code more manageable. Each child class is basically a `Tkinter` frame with input elements. Based on selections from the main GUI, the relevant child class frame is shown. This is achieved using  container and `tkraise()`. I want to reach child class variables from the main class but I cannot with my current code which is given below. I believe there is a problem with the initialization of child classes and/or the inheritance scheme of my app.

What is the correct way to structure a Python application in a setting where you have child classes being shown with container and `tkraise()` scheme and you want to reach child class variables form the main class? I appreciate your help.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import math

 

# Padding values.
tab_padx = (10, 0)
tab_pady = (20, 0)

# Font settings.
font_1 = ("Arial", 13, "bold")

# Main class.
class Main_GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.title("DEMO")

        self.frame_blue_circle = BlueCircle(self, self)
        self.frame_green_square = GreenSquare(self, self)


        # Available shapes.
        self.available_shapes = ["CIRCLE", "SQUARE"]
        # Available colors.
        self.available_colors = ["BLUE", "GREEN"]

        # Function to run when color is changed.
        def color_change(*args):
            self.color = self.option_var_color.get()
            if self.color == "BLUE" and self.shape == "CIRCLE":
                self.type = "BlueCircle"
                self.show_frame("BlueCircle")
            elif self.color == "GREEN" and self.shape == "SQUARE":
                self.show_frame("GreenSquare")
            else:
                self.show_frame("Unimplemented")
            print(f"{self.color} {self.shape}")

        # Function to run when shape is changed.
        def shape_change(*args):
            self.shape = self.option_var_shape.get()
            if self.color == "BLUE" and self.shape == "CIRCLE":
                self.show_frame("BlueCircle")
            elif self.color == "GREEN" and self.shape == "SQUARE":
                self.show_frame("GreenSquare")
            else:
                self.show_frame("Unimplemented")
            print(f"{self.color} {self.shape}")


        #GUI tabs
        self.nb = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.nb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w", padx=10, pady=10)

        #GUI tab1 - Type selection.
        self.tab1 = tk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.nb.add(self.tab1, text="Type")

        #GUI tab2 - Unput for selected type.
        self.tab2 = tk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.nb.add(self.tab2, text="Input")

        #GUI tab3 - Calculate result for selected type with its specific inputs.
        self.tab3 = tk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.nb.add(self.tab3, text="Result")

        # Tab-1 types.
        # Shapes.
        self.Label_shape = tk.Label(self.tab1, text = "Shape: ", font=font_1)
        self.Label_shape.grid(row=10, column=0, padx=tab_padx, pady=tab_pady, sticky="W")

        # Setup variable for disk type dropdown menu.
        self.option_var_shape= tk.StringVar()
        self.option_var_shape.set(self.available_shapes[0])
        self.option_var_shape.trace("w", shape_change)
        self.shape = self.option_var_shape.get()

        self.shape_dropdown_menu = tk.OptionMenu(self.tab1, self.option_var_shape, *self.available_shapes)
        self.shape_dropdown_menu.grid(row=10, column=1, sticky="WE", padx=tab_padx, pady=tab_pady)
        self.shape_dropdown_menu.config(font=font_1, width=20)
        self.shape_dropdown_menu["menu"].config(font=font_1)


        # Colors.
        self.Label_color = tk.Label(self.tab1, text = "Color: ", font=font_1)
        self.Label_color.grid(row=20, column=0, padx=tab_padx, pady=tab_pady, sticky="W")

        # Setup variable for disk type dropdown menu.
        self.option_var_color= tk.StringVar()
        self.option_var_color.set(self.available_colors[0])
        self.option_var_color.trace("w", color_change)
        self.color = self.option_var_color.get()

        self.color_dropdown_menu = tk.OptionMenu(self.tab1, self.option_var_color, *self.available_colors)
        self.color_dropdown_menu.grid(row=20, column=1, sticky="WE", padx=tab_padx, pady=tab_pady)
        self.color_dropdown_menu.config(font=font_1, width=20)
        self.color_dropdown_menu["menu"].config(font=font_1)


        # Tab-2. Show frame based on selection in Tab-1.
        # Container for frames.
        container = tk.Frame(self.tab2)
        container.grid(row=0, column=0)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (BlueCircle, GreenSquare, Unimplemented):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("BlueCircle")


        # Tab-3. Calculate and display result based on Tab-1 and Tab-2.
        # Label to display result.
        result_text = "Result will be displayed here."
        self.Label_result = tk.Label(self.tab3, text = result_text, font=font_1, fg="RED")
        self.Label_result.grid(row=10, column=0, padx=tab_padx, pady=tab_pady, sticky="W")

        self.button = tk.Button(self.tab3, text=f"Print", command=self.print_info)
        self.button.grid(row=20, column=0, sticky="W")

        # print(self.Label_result)



    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def print_info(self):
        bc_text = f"Blue circle radius: {self.frame_blue_circle.radius}"
        print(bc_text)



# Class defining GUI for BlueCircle.
class BlueCircle(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.parent = parent
        self.radius = 0

        # Function to run when rim radius is changed.
        def Entry_change(*args):
            value = self.Entry_var_radius.get()
            
            if value == "":
                self.Entry_var_radius.set(".0")
            else:
                try:
                    self.radius = float(value)
                    print(self.radius)
                except ValueError:
                    self.Entry_var_radius.set("")
                    print(f"Warning! Floating point number only!")


        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Blue Circle", font=font_1, fg="BLUE")
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Radius:")
        self.label.grid(row=1, column=0)

        # Setup variable for entry to use in callback trace.
        self.Entry_var_radius = tk.StringVar()
        self.Entry_var_radius.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, sv=self.Entry_var_radius: Entry_change(self.Entry_var_radius))
        # Entry.
        self.Entry_radius = tk.Entry(self, font=font_1, textvariable=self.Entry_var_radius)
        self.Entry_radius.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.radius = self.Entry_radius.get()


 
# Class defining GUI for GreenSquare.
class GreenSquare(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent

        # Function to run when rim radius is changed.
        def Entry_change(*args):
            value = self.Entry_var_lenght.get()
            if value == "":
                self.Entry_var_lenght.set(".0")
            else:
                try:
                    self.lenght = float(value)
                    self.green_square_area = self.lenght**2
                    # print(f"Side lenght: {self.lenght}. Area: {self.green_square_area:.2f}")
                except ValueError:
                    self.Entry_var_lenght.set("")
                    print(f"Warning! Floating point number only!")


        # Inıtialize variable.
        self.green_square_area = 0


        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Green Squire", font=font_1, fg="GREEN")
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Side lenght:")
        self.label.grid(row=1, column=0)

        # Setup variable for entry to use in callback trace.
        self.Entry_var_lenght = tk.StringVar()
        self.Entry_var_lenght.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, sv=self.Entry_var_lenght: Entry_change(self.Entry_var_lenght))
        # Entry.
        self.lenght = tk.Entry(self, font=font_1, textvariable=self.Entry_var_lenght)
        self.lenght.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.lenght = self.Entry_var_lenght.get()


# Class defining GUI for unimplemented options.
class Unimplemented(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="To be implemented...", font=font_1, fg="RED")
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Main_GUI()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please give an example of a variable from a child that you want to reach and where in your code you want to do this.

Comment: Please try to make a smaller [mcve]. There's a lot of code that seems unnecessary to illustrate your problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley I intended this code to be the minimal reproducible example. This is the shortest code that I could manage to fit all the relevant structures: main class, child class, and frames being raised to view etc.. My original code has child classes that contain too many GUI elements ((labels, inputs, etc.), so having them in a separate file within a child class made sense.

Comment: A minimal example shouldn't need so many widgets. You should be able to illustrate the problem  with classes that are largely empty except for the data you want to pass back and forth. I'm certainly you can illustrate the problem without three tabs in the notebook, for example.

Comment: @quamrana I want to reach the variable radius (self.radius) under class BlueCircle from the main class. Under class Main_GUI, I initialize this class BlueCircle with 'self.frame_blue_circle = BlueCircle(self, self)'. I want to reach this variable in Main_GUI method print_info.

Comment: Yes, I saw that and noted it in my answer.

Comment: @BryanOakley I see your point because I also thought this way. I decided to add them thinking that they might be relevant to this problem since the frames within the child class is placed in a tab in my original code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `self.frame_blue_circle` is not the instance of `BlueCircle` shown inside the notebook, so `self.frame_blue_circle.radius` is not the one input inside the "Input" tab.

The correct instance should be `self.frames['BlueCircle']`, so you need to use `self.frames['BlueCircle'].radius` instead:

```py
def print_info(self):
    bc_text = f"Blue circle radius: {self.frames['BlueCircle'].radius}"
    print(bc_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `__init__()` method you have: `self.frame_blue_circle = BlueCircle(self, self)`. This means that anywhere in your `Main_GUI` class (I mean typically other methods) you can access this and then its `radius` attribute.

In fact, you already do this here:

```py
    def print_info(self):
        bc_text = f"Blue circle radius: {self.frame_blue_circle.radius}"
        print(bc_text)
```

Comment: In the last tab I have a button that is linked to this method print_info. It is supposed to print the value grabbed from the child class. But it doesn't. Probably I am missing something fundamental here. I suspect passing two self to BlueCircle may have something to do with it. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I can't see why your code won't work. The `BlueCircle` class has its `radius` attribute independently of the parameters. If it doesn't work, how do you know? If nothing is printed, maybe something stops the button working. If you get an error printed, you should have reported that.

Comment: Under class BlueCircle method Entry_change, I have a line print(self.radius). So when I enter a value I know the radius changes since it is printed. Outside in the Main_GUI, when I click on the button in the last tab I expect the print_info method to grab and plot is input value (which is float). The text portion is printed but the variable portion is not, thus my conclusion that it is not working as intended. But I do not get an error. I didn't want this to be a "debug my code" type of question. If what I do is methodically correct, then I am missing something very fundamental. Thank you!

Comment: `but the variable portion is not,`. No, you can't have one without the other. If you weren't able to access `self.frame_blue_circle.radius` you would get an error traceback. If somehow the `radius` member becomes a string of spaces you just won't see anything.

Comment: Try: `bc_text = f"Blue circle radius: {self.frame_blue_circle.radius}, {type(self.frame_blue_circle.radius)}"`